# Read raster value at mouse position

Tags: qgis, raster

I have raster layer imported in QGIS. How can I read value of the variable represented by the raster at mouse position? I just have a new raster layer and I want to read values at random places to have a basic idea about the raster.

I prefer not to create point layer for this purpose, but if it is needed, please tell me how to do it that way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have finally found an answer in a [feature request for this functionality in status bar](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/1208). The feature is not planned, however there is a QGIS plugin called *Value Tool* which  does this. It fetches the current value at the mouse position of various layers. It can also plot graphs.

Answer (score 7):

The ticket you refer to is over four years old and the ability to read raster values at the mouse position exists in both version 1.8 and 1.9.  Ensure your raster layer is selected in the layers list.  Then use the 'Identify Features' tool (blue 'i' and white arrow icon) and click on your raster.  The values are displayed in a popup (an example popup from a raster I happened to have on-screen at the time is below).

[image]

Comment: thanks, so I don't need to install anything! On the other hand it is much more handy to see the values just after hovering mouse over that area...

Comment: What if you don't know what layer you are clicking on?

Comment: You know which raster layer you are clicking on because you select it first in the layers list.